# Internal anchor Position on firefox mobile (on android)

Tags: html, css, firefox, mobile, cross-browser

I have a homepage with a number of sections - each of these is linked to from the main menu:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- nav used on all pages -->
        <a href="#nav" class="toggle-nav">
            menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <nav class="main-nav" id="nav">
            <a href="/#item1">Link</a>
            <a href="/#item2">Link</a>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <!-- homepage -->
    <main>
        <section id="item1">some content here </section>
        <section id="item2">some other content here </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

(possibly) relevant css:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    header .main-nav a {
        display: block;
    }

    .tiggle-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The idea is that I should be able to click on 'Item 1' in the menu across the entire site, and land at that particular section of the homepage.

This works really well, *except* on firefox mobile, where the clicking on the homepage internal anchor link **from any other internal page** will result in the homepage loading anywhere between 100 and 200px away from the intended location.

Interestingly, if I refresh the page *after* the homepage has initially loaded, firefox mobile can find the internal anchor with no problems - i.e this is only a problem when navigating from the internal page to the homepage.

What is happening here? Does this have something to do with firefox mobile not loading CSS until *after* it has found the internal anchor?

And importantly, how can I make firefox mobile find the correct location first time?

Any insights very much appreciated.

Full css and html is live at http://whoisnicoleharris.com

Comment: Hi, the HTML snippet is not sufficient to look into this issue. Could you show me how your CSS is set up, and whether the HTML segments are nested in other containers. It's most likely relative-absolute positioning issue.

Comment: The site is actually live at http://whoisnicoleharris.com (probably easier than reproducing all the code here)

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing. When you say Firefox Mobile, are you talking Firefox for Android (tried, could not reproduce), Firefox OS (tried v2.0, could not reproduce), the one that floated around a few years ago under the name Fennec, or something else entirely? I followed the same steps as Schien said worked for him, so I assume I'm using the wrong browser unless hardware is marking the difference.

Comment: The issue I am experiencing is using Firefox mobile on Android 5.0.1.  I do not have the same issue using Chrome on the same phone, so I assume this is a FF only issue.

Comment: I just tested this on Firefox mobile on Android 4.4. I cannot reproduce. I've tested from the homepage to the sections, and from internal pages from the sections. I tried following Schien's reproduction instructions step by step ... Connect Page ... Writing .. the positioning is working perfectly. Have you changed something since posting this question?

Comment: It looks like your page is changing heights after the initial load.  Anything like this might confuse the browser as it figures out where to scroll to and then the page changes size all the sudden.  A refresh will sometimes just do a smarter (lighter) reload, which may explain why it doesn't happen there.

Answer (score 2):

In the main.js change 400 to 0 for the below part:

```
$('#top').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},400);
});
```

The code looks like below after the change:

```
$('#top').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
});
```

Tested here, seems can solve the problem, but I can't say why exactly. It must due to the additional 400 pixels being added above the anchor link.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following to reproduce the error.

I went to the connect page, and then click on "Writing". The positioning is indeed off. I then disabled JavaScript to rely on the anchor. It worked correctly.

My solution is to detect a specific object on the page to decide between JavaScript scrolling vs. direct anchoring.

```
if (document.getElementById('homepagebookmark')){
  //do scroll
} else {
  //leave it be
}
```

Comment: I've just tested this locally, and removing the scrolling JS has no impact for me.